# How to setup a default hiera lookup value

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am setting up my Puppet code using Hiera such that if a value is not found in Hiera, it assigns a default value to it. I am not getting the desired results and wanted to know how others did it :

```
lookup( <NAME>, [<VALUE TYPE>], [<MERGE BEHAVIOR>], [<DEFAULT VALUE>] )
```

I think I found the answer 
https://www.devco.net/archives/2016/03/13/the-puppet-4-lookup-function.php
, will try it shortly

```
lookup({"name" => "some::thing", "default_value" => "default"})
```

Comment: Also if you are using the classic `hiera` functions, then the last argument to them will be the default value.

Comment: Does that mean, I dont need to add the hash like structure, but instead simply use
 lookup({ "name" => "some::variable", "default_value"})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was :

```
$myvar1 = lookup( { "name" => "myvar1", "default_value" => "default" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally , if the value logpath is declared in hiera . Puppet manifest will pick up the value automatically .If it is not found in Hiera , then puppet agent will error out saying that value is not found .

If the value is not declared in Hiera , there is always a way where in one can declare the value in puppet manifest . if the value is not find in Puppet Hiera , then manifest is looked into for the puppet value .

As a good practice , value is declared in hiera and as well as puppet manifest .If the value is not found in Hiera , puppet will look into variable present in manifest

Answer (score 0):

In Puppet 7 (at least), the following syntax works:

```rb
$myvar1 = lookup('myvar1', default_value => 'default')
```