# Difference between puppet hiera() and lookup() in puppet module code

Tags: puppet

I am trying to switch from hiera() to lookup() but it doesn't work.
I used to have the following line of code:

```
if (hiera("ntp::enabled",0) == 1 ){
```

and it worked correctly.

After simply replacing hiera with lookup:

```
if (lookup("ntp::enabled",0) == 1 ){
```

I am getting a huge error:

```
    Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, 'lookup' expects one of:
  (NameType = Variant[String, Array[String]] name, ValueType = Type value_type?, MergeType = Variant[String[1], Hash[String, Scalar]] merge?)
    rejected: parameter 'value_type' expects a ValueType = Type value, got Integer
  (NameType = Variant[String, Array[String]] name, Optional[ValueType] value_type, Optional[MergeType] merge, DefaultValueType = Any default_value)
    rejected: expects 4 arguments, got 2
  (NameType = Variant[String, Array[String]] name, ValueType = Type value_type?, MergeType = Variant[String[1], Hash[String, Scalar]] merge?)
    rejected: parameter 'value_type' expects a ValueType = Type value, got Integer
  (OptionsWithName = Struct[{'name' => NameType = Variant[String, Array[String]], 'value_type' => Optional[ValueType = Type], 'default_value' => DefaultValueType = Any, 'override' => Optional[Hash[String, Any]], 'default_values_hash' => Optional[Hash[String, Any]], 'merge' => Optional[MergeType = Variant[String[1], Hash[String, Scalar]]]}] options_hash, BlockType = Callable[NameType = Variant[String, Array[String]]] block?)
    rejected: expects 1 argument, got 2
  (Variant[String, Array[String]] name, OptionsWithoutName = Struct[{'value_type' => Optional[ValueType = Type], 'default_value' => DefaultValueType = Any, 'override' => Optional[Hash[String, Any]], 'default_values_hash' => Optional[Hash[String, Any]], 'merge' => Optional[MergeType = Variant[String[1], Hash[String, Scalar]]]}] options_hash, BlockType = Callable[NameType = Variant[String, Array[String]]] block?)
    rejected: parameter 'options_hash' expects an OptionsWithoutName = Struct[{'value_type' => Optional[ValueType = Type], 'default_value' => DefaultValueType = Any, 'override' => Optional[Hash[String, Any]], 'default_values_hash' => Optional[Hash[String, Any]], 'merge' => Optional[MergeType = Variant[String[1], Hash[String, Scalar]]]}] value, got Integer (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/sandbox/modules/ntp_mycompany/manifests/init.pp, line: 38, column: 5) on node mybox.mycompany.com
```

Probably I am missing something simple but I thought that one can simply replace deprecated hiera() call with newer lookup() call.

Comment: I do not recall seeing that in the documentation. You likely need to update your usage as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a puppet expert, but looking at [the documentation for lookup](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/hiera_use_function.html) it seems to require a different set of parameters than the `hiera()` call:

```
lookup( <NAME>, [<VALUE TYPE>], [<MERGE BEHAVIOR>], [<DEFAULT VALUE>] )
```

If you wanted to provide a default value using positional options, you would also need to fill in values for `<VALUE TYPE>` and `<MERGE BEHAVIOR>`.  It looks like an alternative is to provide a hash of arguments instead of list. If you continue reading those docs, you see an alternative way of calling the function is:

```
lookup( [<NAME>], <OPTIONS HASH> )
```

An example of that mechanism might look [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606675/how-to-setup-a-default-hiera-lookup-value):

```
lookup({"name" => "some::thing", "default_value" => "default"})
```

Comment: Yes. I've managed to fix the issue by adding "default_value" key.